# Can you direct files to a flash drive?

Tags: dual-boot

In the future I would like to dual boot macOS and Ubuntu or something similar and I would like to run the os on the laptop's drive but then direct the files that I download to an external drive? Is that possible?

Comment: What is the actual problem that you face?  When downloading files from your web browser, for example, you get a file picker and you can choose to download things wherever you want.  What is the issue you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: *yes*. It is you, not the operating system, who is in charge of deciding where your files go. So in principle, no problem.

The only caveat you may face is that all operating systems you use must support the file system on the external drive for this to work.